# How to compare a return type of a lambda function in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda, types, c++17

I've been trying to find out the return type of a lambda expression to know if the function returns a `void`, or not.

My first thought was using `std::invoke_result`, however that did not work as expected, since it doesnt work with `std::is_same`, which expects two types.

Here's what i've been trying

```
auto lamb = [] ( int x ) { cout << x << endl; };
is_same<(invoke_result<decltype(lamb),int>),void>;
```

The error is:

```
 trabapply2.cc:32:50: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 is_same<(invoke_result<decltype(lamb),int>),void>;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the parentheses around the expression. It's a syntax error. You also need to use `invoke_result_t` as `invoke_result` is just the type trait type. This will work: `static_assert(std::is_same_v<(std::invoke_result_t<decltype(lamb),int>), void>);`

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick, I dont really know why the :: didnt work properly but you fixed the problem ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the superfluous parentheses around `invoke_result`, and get `type` from `invoke_result`, and get `value` from `is_same`. e.g.

```
is_same<invoke_result<decltype(lamb), int>::type, void>::value // gives true or false
```

or

```
is_same_v<invoke_result_t<decltype(lamb), int>, void> // since C++17
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ODTQiSEuEnTb9kBR)

Comment: Thank you, the second solution worked when i was doing it from inside a function, while the first one did not, not sure why, thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @JoãoMaia For dependent names, such as in templates, you might need adding `typename` like `typename invoke_result<decltype(foo), int>::type`.